# Alter text in pandas column based on names

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, text, nlp

**Background**

I have the following sample `df`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['Jon J Mmith is Here from **BLOCK** until **BLOCK**', 
                                   'No P_Name Found here', 
                                   'Jane Ann Doe is Also here until **BLOCK** ',
                                '**BLOCK** was **BLOCK** Tom Tcker is Not here but **BLOCK** '], 

                      'P_ID': [1,2,3,4], 
                      'P_Name' : ['Mmith, Jon J', 'Hder, Mary', 'Doe, Jane Ann', 'Tcker, Tom'],
                      'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']

                     })

#rearrange columns
df = df[['Text','N_ID', 'P_ID', 'P_Name']]
df


                         Text                       N_ID    P_ID    P_Name
0   Jon J Mmith is Here from **BLOCK** until **BLOCK**  A1        1 Mmith, Jon J
1   No P_Name Found here                            A2        2 Hder, Mary
2   Jane Ann Doe is Also here until **BLOCK**           A3        3 Doe, Jane Ann
3   **BLOCK** was **BLOCK** Tom Tcker is Not here but  A4         4 Hcker, Tom
```

**Goal**

1) In `Text` column, add  `**BLOCK**` to the value (e.g. `Jon J Mmith`) that corresponds to the value found in `P_Name`

**Desired Output**

```
                         Text                       N_ID    P_ID    P_Name
0   **BLOCK** is Here from **BLOCK** until **BLOCK**        A1        1 Mmith, Jon J
1   No P_Name Found here                            A2        2 Hder, Mary
2   **BLOCK** is Also here until **BLOCK**              A3        3 Doe, Jane Ann
3   **BLOCK** was **BLOCK** **BLOCK** is Not here but     A4          4 Tcker, Tom
```

The desired output can occur in the same `Text` col or a `new_col` can be made

**Question**

How do I achieve my desired output?

Comment: There may be other capitalized words

Comment: I updated the wording in **Goal**. Hopefully this is clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
>>> df['Text'].replace(df['P_Name'].str.split(', *').apply(lambda l: ' '.join(l[::-1])),'**BLOCK**',regex=True)
0           **BLOCK** is here from **BLOCK** until **BLOCK**
1                                 No P_Name found here
2                  **BLOCK** is also here until **BLOCK**
3    **BLOCK** was **BLOCK** **BLOCK** is not here but **...
```

You can use `replace=True` to do this in place, or create a new column with `df['new_col']=` the above. What this does is splits the `P_name` column, joins it in reverse with a space, and replaces it in your `Text` column.

Comment: @ER_18 add `.str.title().` before the original `.str` in  `df['P_Name'].str` so you have `df['P_Name'].str.title().str` and leave the rest.

Comment: @ER_18 exactly.