# Alter text in pandas column based on names list

Tags: regex, pandas, list, text, apply

**Background**

I have the following sample `df`

```
import pandas as pd
Names =    [list(['Jon', 'Mith', 'jon', 'John']),
           list(['Mark', 'Marky', 'marcs']),
           list(['Bob', 'bobby', 'Bobs'])]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['Jon J Mmith is Here and jon John from ', 
                                   'When he came Mark was Marky but not marcs so', 
                                   'I like Bob and bobby and also Bobs diner '], 

                      'P_ID': [1,2,3], 
                      'P_Name' : Names

                     })

#rearrange columns
df = df[['Text', 'P_ID', 'P_Name']]
df


    Text                                       P_ID  P_Name
0   Jon J Mmith is Here and jon John from       1   [Jon, Smith, jon, John]
1   When he came Mark was Marky but not marcs   2   [Mark, Marky, marcs]
2   I like Bob and bobby and also Bobs diner    3   [Bob, bobby, Bobs]
```

This `df` is a variation from an "old question" seen here [Alter text in pandas column based on names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029538/alter-text-in-pandas-column-based-on-names). The only difference in my new `df` and "new question" is the format of the names in the `P_Name` column as seen below:

```
 #old names from old question
 array(['Mmith, Jon J', 'Hider, Mary', 'Doe, Jane Ann', 'Tucker, Tom'], dtype=object) 
 #new names from new question
 array([list(['Jon', 'Smith', 'jon', 'John']),
        list(['Mark', 'Marky', 'marcs']), list(['Bob', 'bobby', 'Bobs'])], dtype=object)
```

**Goal**

In `Text` column, add  `**BLOCK**` to the values (e.g. `[Jon, Mmith, jon, John]`) that corresponds to the value found in `P_Name`

**Problem**

When I use the solution in the "old question" taken from [Alter text in pandas column based on names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029538/alter-text-in-pandas-column-based-on-names)

```
 df['Text'].replace(df['P_Name'].str.split(', *').apply(lambda l: ' '.join(l[::-1])),'**BLOCK**',regex=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-895f7ea46849> in <module>()
----> 1 df['Text'].replace(df['P_Name'].str.split(', *').apply(lambda l: ' '.join(l[::-1])),'**BLOCK**',regex=True)



/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2353             else:
   2354                 values = self.asobject
-> 2355                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2356 
   2357         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer (pandas/_libs/lib.c:66645)()

<ipython-input-79-895f7ea46849> in <lambda>(l)
----> 1 df['Text'].replace(df['P_Name'].str.split(', *').apply(lambda l: ' '.join(l[::-1])),'**BLOCK**',regex=True)

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

**Desired Outcome**

I would like the following, similar to the answer in the "old question" [Alter text in pandas column based on names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029538/alter-text-in-pandas-column-based-on-names)

```
               Text                                       P_ID  P_Name
0   **BLOCK** J **BLOCK** is Here and **BLOCK** **BLOCK** from       1   [Jon, Smith, jon, John]
1   When he came **BLOCK** was **BLOCK** but not **BLOCK**         2   [Mark, Marky, marcs]
2   I like **BLOCK** and **BLOCK** and also **BLOCK** diner        3   [Bob, bobby, Bobs]
```

**Question**

How do I achieve my desired outcome given that my `P_Name` column now contains list of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need [`series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) which takes a list as arg:

> to_replace : str, regex, list, dict, Series, int, float, or None

```
df=df.assign(Text=df.Text.replace(df.P_Name,'**BLOCK**',regex=True))
```

Comment: @ER_18 `df['new']=df.Text.replace(df.P_Name,'**PHI**',regex=True)`

Comment: perfect! Thank you :)