# modification of alter text in pandas column based on names

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas, replace

**Background**

I have the following df which is a modification of [Alter text in pandas column based on names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029538/alter-text-in-pandas-column-based-on-names)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['Jon J Doe works ', 
                                   'So is Mary Doe, works too',
                                'Jane Ann, Doe doesnt',
                                 'Jone, Dow doesnt either'], 

                      'P_ID': [1,2,3,4],
                   'P_Name' : ['Doe, Jon J', 'Doe, Mary', 'Doe, Jane Ann', 'Dow, Jone' ]

                     })


P_ID    P_Name           Text
0   1   Doe, Jon J       Jon J Doe works
1   2   Doe, Mary        So is Mary Doe, works too
2   3   Doe, Jane Ann    Jane Ann, Doe doesnt
3   4   Dow, Jone        Jone, Dow doesnt either
```

And the following block of code works to block names like `Jon J Doe` but it doesnt work when a name like `Jane Ann Doe` has a character in between e.g. `Jane Ann, Doe` or `Jone! Dow`

```
df['NewText'] = df['Text'].replace(df['P_Name'].str.split(', *').apply(lambda l: ' '.join(l[::-1])),'**BLOCK**',regex=True)
```

**Output**

```
    P_ID    P_Name    Text                     NewText
0   1   Doe, Jon J    Jon J Doe works          **BLOCK** works
1   2   Doe, Mary     So is Mary Doe, works     So is **BLOCK**, works 
2   3   Doe, Jane Ann Jane Ann, Doe doesnt      Jane Ann, Doe doesnt
3   4   Dow, Jone     Jone,Dow doesnt either    Jone, Dow doesnt either
```

**Goal**

1) Tweak the code above to take into account for `,` (or any other characters that may be in between the names)

*(I know I can strip commas, but I need to leave them in)*

**Desired Output**

```
    P_ID    P_Name    Text                     NewText
0   1   Doe, Jon J    Jon J Doe works          **BLOCK** works
1   2   Doe, Mary     So is Mary Doe, works     So is **BLOCK**, works 
2   3   Doe, Jane Ann Jane Ann, Doe doesnt      **BLOCK**  doesnt
3   4   Dow, Jone     Jone,Dow doesnt either    **BLOCK** doesnt either
```

**Question**

How do I tweak my code to get my desired output?

Comment: are there only these three names `Jon J Doe` ,  `Mary Doe`, `Jane Ann, Doe`  and `Jone, Dow` ? if this is the case then we easily make a case.

Comment: in this sample yes but in my real dataset there are ~700K

Comment: okay, based on the sample i placed the solution see if that helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df['NewText'] = df['Text'].replace( r'('+ df['P_Name'].str.split('\W+').str.join('|')+'|\W+){3,}', ' **BLOCK** ', regex=True)
```

Comment: how would I incorporate `re.split(r'\W+', 'John, Ann Doe')` into `df['NewText'] = df['Text'].replace(df['P_Name'].str.split(', *').apply(lambda l: ' '.join(l[::-1])),'**BLOCK**',regex=True)` ?

Comment: `df['Text'].replace(df['P_Name'].str.split(r"\W+").apply(lambda l: ' '.join(l[::-1])),'**BLOCK**',regex=True)`

Comment: I tried it but I still get `Jane Ann, Doe doesnt` and `Jone, Dow doesnt either`

Comment: sorry for the delay. updated the solution. It's a bit "sticked to the example", but works

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there are multiple such cases, but in case you have limited

### Sample DataSet:

```
>>> df
   P_ID         P_Name                       Text
0     1     Doe, Jon J           Jon J Doe works
1     2      Doe, Mary  So is Mary Doe, works too
2     3  Doe, Jane Ann       Jane Ann, Doe doesnt
3     4      Dow, Jone    Jone, Dow doesnt either
```

You can create dict combination and apply that to the dataFrame to get the result.

```
>>> replace_values = {'Jon J Doe': '**BLOCK**', 'Mary Doe': '**BLOCK**', 'Jane Ann, Doe': '**BLOCK**', 'Jone, Dow': '**BLOCK**'}
```

### Resulted dataFrame:

```
>>> df = df.replace(replace_values, regex=True)
>>> df
   P_ID         P_Name                        Text
0     1     Doe, Jon J            **BLOCK** works
1     2      Doe, Mary  So is **BLOCK**, works too
2     3  Doe, Jane Ann            **BLOCK** doesnt
3     4      Dow, Jone     **BLOCK** doesnt either
```

Comment: this works for this toy example. But any idea how I would be able to do the same when 1) 750K names 2) it's hard to tell where the `,` would be e.g. `Jane, Ann Doe`  vs `Jane Ann, Doe` ?

Comment: I was looking for this for a small subset of data, for me as learner its good starter ..thank you sir.