# Block text in pandas column based on names

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, text, replace

**Background**

This question is a variation of [Alter text in pandas column based on names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029538/alter-text-in-pandas-column-based-on-names).

I have the following `df` which intentionally has various issues

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['But now Smith,J J is Here from Smithsville', 
                                   'Maryland is HYDER,A MARY Found here ', 
                                   'hey here is Annual Doe,Jane Ann until ',
                                'The tuckered was Tucker,Tom is Not here but'], 

                      'P_ID': [1,2,3,4], 
                      'P_Name' : ['SMITH,J J', 'HYDER,A MARY', 'DOE,JANE ANN', 'TUCKER,TOM T'],
                      'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']

                     })
```

**Output**

```
   N_ID P_ID P_Name         Text
0   A1  1   SMITH,J J       But now Smith,J J is Here from Smithsville
1   A2  2   HYDER,A MARY    Maryland is HYDER,A MARY Found here
2   A3  3   DOE,JANE ANN    hey here is Annual Doe,Jane Ann until
3   A4  4   TUCKER,TOM T    The tuckered was Tucker,Tom is Not here but
```

**Goal**

1) For names in `P_Name` e.g. `SMITH,J J` block name with `**BLOCK**` in the corresponding `Text` column

2) Create `New_Text` column

**Desired Output**

```
    N_ID P_ID P_Name Text   New_Text
0                           But now **BLOCK** is Here from Smithsville
1                           Maryland is **BLOCK**  Found here
2                           hey here is Annual **BLOCK**  until
3                           The tuckered was **BLOCK** is Not here but
```

**Question**

How do I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df['New_Text'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['Text'].lower().replace(x['P_Name'].lower(), '**BLOCK**'), axis=1)
```

your example has some white space issues, but it should work with properly constructed examples

#### Output (modifying white space issues, last row doesn't have a full match)

```
0          but now BLOCK is here from smithsville
1                   maryland is BLOCK found here 
2                 hey here is annual BLOCK until 
3    the tuckered was tucker, tom is not here but
```

Comment: The white space issues are intentional. My actual data is pretty similar to what I have above, including white space. Would the above code drastically change to account for white space?

Comment: well, that was not part of the original question. If that is the case, then you need fuzzy matching. Either that or remove all whitespace and do some very creative whitespace insertion. But your new question is quite harder, so be patient!

Comment: It was but I think I just wasn't clear about it in my original background statement. I can just tweak the above question to eliminate the white space issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to remove the white spaces then use the `replace` function with `regex=True`

```
# new data frame without the whitespace inconsistencies
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['But now Smith,J J is Here from Smithsville', 
                                   'Maryland is HYDER,A MARY Found here ', 
                                   'hey here is Annual Doe,Jane Ann until ',
                                'The tuckered was Tucker,Tom T is Not here but'], 

                      'P_ID': [1,2,3,4], 
                      'P_Name' : ['SMITH,J J', 'HYDER,A MARY', 'DOE,JANE ANN', 'TUCKER,TOM T'],
                      'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']

                     })

print(df.Text.str.lower().replace(df.P_Name.str.lower(), '**BLOCK**', regex=True))

0    but now **BLOCK** is here from smithsville
1             maryland is **BLOCK** found here 
2           hey here is annual **BLOCK** until 
3    the tuckered was **BLOCK** is not here but
Name: Text, dtype: object
```